# Bootstrap wrong alignment of items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I'm new to bootstrap, I use col-md-* grid system to make a list of items. Each item is something like the picture below

[image]

The source code in [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTgGX/1/).

The problem is when I decrease the size of the browser windows, the red rectangle goes in the wrong place. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: use media queries, you can read about them at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to be the right but not all the way to the right you should use the bootstrap `grid off-sets.`

**Second** 
Take a look at this [grid example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and see what resizes at smaller windows to full-width.

also the the responsiveness of bootstrap at certain widths makes `col-md-6` 100%

it seems like you will need to  `col-xs-6` instead.

I have updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTgGX/2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTgGX/2/

Comment: Thanks, I changed `<div class="col-md-1">` to `<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-2 pull-right" >` and it works.

Comment: `<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-2 pull-right" ` is the same thing as `<div class="col-xs-2 pull-right" ` col-xs-2  over writes col-md-1